# Mobile and desktop version - Avoiding two elements with the same ID

Tags: html, css

I have two forms, one for desktop version, and another one for mobile version. The content is the same, but the display is very different.

Because it's a long form, I do have two different "div", one for each version.

```
<div class="desktop-version">
    <!-- blah blah blah my long form -->
</div>

<div class="mobile-version">
    <!-- blah blah blah my long form -->
</div>
```

At first, I just wanted to put a "display: none" in my CSS file to hide one form, and let the other one visible.

But then I realize if I do that, I will have two fields with the same ID (one visible and one hidden). And obviously, I don't wanna have two fields with the same ID...

Does anyone have a proper method to solve my problem please ?

Thanks

Comment: why does it need to be id? can't it be a class

Comment: it can't be a class only for my fields, I use ID to validate, fill, load, save (etc.) my form

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.innerWidth` to determine the width of window and do thing according to it.
Assume HTML

```html
<div class="desktop-version">
  <input name="email" type="email">
</div>

<div class="mobile-version">
  <input name="email" type="email">
</div>
```

In JS

```js
var mobileWidth = 769; // in px
var formParent;

if (window.innerWidth < mobileWidth) {
  // Yay, on mobile, do whatever
  formParent = document.querySelector('.mobile-version');
} else {
  // You're on desktop
  formParent = document.querySelector('.desktop-version');
}

// Access value of <input name="email">
var email = formParent.querySelector('[name="email"]').value;
```

You won't have to give ID to element, you can access them using `querySelector()` using CSS like identifier. Here we are changing the parent element according to screen size. We can do the rest after that.